# Performance cost of threading constructs: missed optimisations and memory allocation

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

We are experiencing a strange phenomenon in which the inclusion of a header file results in a 5-10% performance penalty in certain memory-allocation-intensive workloads.

This header file declares a thread pool as a global variable. This thread pool is never used in any capacity (yet) in the application. That is, apart from the creation of this static thread pool at program startup, the application is completely single-threaded. The performance penalty disappears once the header is removed.

From a bit of researching, it seems like a multithreaded application can incur in some performance penalty due to certain compiler optimisations not being possible any more. Is it possible that such optimisations are being turned off whenever a threading-related construct is instantiated in any form or capacity?

Or, since the performance penalty seems to be most evident while performing numerous memory allocations, is it possible that during the compilation/linking phase the compiler realises that threading constructs are instantiated and thus it switches to a thread-safe memory allocator?

This happens on a Linux 64 bit workstation, with both GCC and clang. The standard threading primitives from C++11 are being used.

**EDIT** I should also probably mention that, according to our tests, when using the tcmalloc allocator instead of the default one, the performance difference seems to go away.

Comment: this is actually fascinating. are you in a position to post a minimal compilable example to demonstrate the phenomenon?

Comment: Do the object files change aside from the added variables?

Comment: Does this "creation of static thread pool at program startup" involve any memory allocations in main and/or worker threads?

Comment: You have made some assumption without supporting them. However on Linux there is a tool to measure performance and to find contention points. It is `perf` (https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page). You need to use it and find out exactly the source of problem (instead of guessing). http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html is a kind of well known blog about tuning performace. As a hint: `perf record` - record application performance using CPU cycles (for CPU intensive apps), `perf record -F 99`  record application performance in order to find contention points.

Comment: If optimisations are turned off, then you should be able to see that when diffing the output of `objdump -d`. Otherwise ... are those threads "alive"? Then the cause could be that the OS is giving them time slices, though that would indicate an unfortunate implementation of the threading facilities.

Comment: The obvious question is *how* are you measuring performance? Measuring what you actually want to measure and making sure it's a statistically significant difference is a hard problem that is very easy to do wrong in a subtle way

Comment: Could it be the the thread pool library fiddles with `mallopt()` when initialised? I read somewhere you can tune arenas/etc using it.

Comment: It may seem obvious, but easily overlooked, but could this header be over-riding another function? Does this header link to a library that may have an abnormal runtime linkage?
I've seen headers for windows projects that overide stncpy and even malloc (often to use the windows "safe" versions - strncpy_s etc).

Answer (score 1):

Multi-threaded malloc and some other checked functions incur a lock cost, consistent with what you are seeing.  I would expect the malloc implementation to change to the threaded (and locked) version by some directive in the thread header file.

This is a reasonable cost, and results in a more understandable output from the program, at the cost of strange performance changes for single threaded examples.